# Need to convert c code under VC++ 6.0 to MIPS assembly

Tags: c, visual-c++, mips

I am trying to make the VC++6.0 to compile my code to a MIPS assembly so I could read it and copy that code.

Is there a way to do so ? if not, is there an other way under windows ? I am trying Cygwin but no clue how to deal with...

thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studion basically only supports the targets that Windows run on, and MIPS is not included in this.

You will need a so-calles *cross compiler*. There are a number of such compilers out there, the most common one is *gcc*.

You will, however, have to run them from a command-line and not from within Visual Studio.

Comment: can you help me how to install a gcc and produce my MIPS code file ?